# Wordpress: how to limit post-nav to specific category?

Tags: wordpress, post, navigation, categories

I'm setting up my first Wordpress site. I have limited knowledge and understanding of its inner working. (Bear that in mind, please)
I setup 3 different pages that show posts based on their categories.
Though, once your reading one post, from either pages, the Next Post/Previous Post navigation still cycle thru all the posts regardless of their categorie.
I would like to limit this navigation to posts within the category of the page the reader is reading from.

Is that at all feasable and if so, can you help me out understanding how to do it?
Or if there is a plugin that does that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's covered in the WP docs. Set in_same_cat to true.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/next_post_link/

If the links are already in your theme, you'll need to edit them.

Comment: As I mentionned, I have limited knowledge of WP (I'm learning though), where would I find those links in my theme, or within WP itself?
The link you gave me at the Codex doesn't say where to look for this, in which PHP file they're tucked into.
I'm guessing it would not be as simple as just creating a function.php and putting the code in there, right?

Comment: Actually, I think I found it in my theme. There is a post-nav.php file that has the previous and next post code in there.
The file is in the INCLUDES folder of the parent theme. 
As I don't want to alter the parent theme files, do I have to create an INCLUDES folder in the child theme with the modified post-nav.php file there?

Comment: Well, nothing like experimenting to learn a lesson. I just recreated the INCLUDES folder with the modified post-nav.php in the child theme and it all works.
Though, it should be an option when you create a page to include or exclude a category or categories. Isn't that a basic functionality for a blog?
Anyways, thanks a lot for steering me in the right direction, @Chris-Fernandini

Comment: Glad you figured it out - location varies from theme to theme. Mind marking my answe as correct?

Comment: Done! I can't upped your answer though, I don't have a "reputation" yet in here. ;)
Thanks again.